# function javascript to set the position in google maps

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, javafx-2

Good afternoon,

I am developping a javaFX application and now I want to include on it a map using google maps
I have successfully dispaly the map on javaFX using this code on a html file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Java-Buddy: Google Maps</title>
<script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
<style>#mapcanvas { height: 360px; width: 100%}</style>



</head>
<body>
<h1>Java-Buddy: Google Maps</h1>
<div id="mapcanvas">

    <script type="text/javascript">

                                        var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(35.857908, 10.598997);
                                        var Options = {
                                            zoom: 15,
                                            center: latlng,
                                            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
                                        };
                                        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("mapcanvas"), Options);
                                        //var carMarkerImage = new google.maps.MarkerImage('resources/images/car.png');
                                        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                                            position: new google.maps.LatLng(35.857908, 10.598997),
                                            map: map,
                                            draggable: false,
                                            //icon: carMarkerImage,
                                            title: "",
                                            autoPan: true

                                        });


                                    </script>


</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I want to set the postition of the map using the controller class

I can do it with this event code

```
 public void handle(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
                            webEngine.executeScript("document.myFunction(longitude, latitude)");}
```

I am new on javascript, and I want to know how to write the javascript function that allow me to set or to change the current position on the map

Thank you

Comment: first you'll have to set editable:true

Answer (score 2):

```
function myFunction(longitude, latitude){
    map.setCenter(new google.maps.LatLng(latitude, longitude));
}
```